# Qual a diferença dos métodos replace() e replaceAll()?

Tags: java, string, regex

Estava lendo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) para desenvolver corretamente uma máscara e salvar sem ela.

Entretanto me deparei com esta duvida dos métodos `replace` e `replaceAll` para as minhas `string`.

Qual a diferença entre ambos, aparentemente ambos servem para o mesmo propósito.

Comment: A diferença é que o primeiro utiliza uma sequencia de chars para fazer a substituição, o segundo utiliza regex. Ambos são para a mesma finalidade, só muda isso.

Comment: @diegofm menos mal então nao tem perigo usar um ou outro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, ambos servem para o mesmo propósito. O [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) substitui todas ocorrências de uma caractere ou uma sequência de `char` em uma *string*, enquanto que o [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) faz o mesmo baseado-se em um padrão de expressão regular.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O replace utiliza o replaceAll até, segundo o [código fonte](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29).